# Extending laravel's SeedCommand

Tags: php, laravel-5

Trying to make an extension to the core `db:seed` command to add a couple of necessary options. 
Extending the `Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand` 
and registering my command in `Kernel.php` give me following output when running `php artisan` :

`[Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException]

  Target [Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Console\Commands\TenantSeeder].`

Any hints what I am missing ? the class itself below :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand;
use Illuminate\Console\ConfirmableTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface as Resolver;

class TenantSeeder extends SeedCommand
{
    use ConfirmableTrait;
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'tenant:seed';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * The connection resolver instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface
     */
    protected $resolver;

    /**
     * Create a new database seed command instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface  $resolver
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Resolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->resolver = $resolver;
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        $opts = parent::getOptions();
        return array_merge($opts, [
            ['tenant', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Tenant is required to generate tenant-specific data'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this if you are using a regular database like MySQL:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;

class CustomSeedCommand extends SeedCommand
{

    public function __construct(DatabaseManager $databaseManager)
    {

        parent::__construct($databaseManager);
    }

}
```